# How to get length of MP3 file in Perl?

Tags: tags, mp3

I used MP3::Tag to get ID3 information from mp3 file.

But I don't know how to get length of mp3 file.. 
I mean duration.

# get some information about the file in the easiest way

($title, $track, $artist, $album, $comment, $year, $genre) = $mp3->autoinfo();

This one don't have function which is getting length from ID3.

Anyone knows how I can get length of mp3 file in Perl?

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for the answer, install [MP3::Info](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MP3%3a%3aInfo) and use:

```
$mp3->time_mm_ss();
```

Other things you can use:

```
total_secs()

total_secs_int()

total_mins()

leftover_secs()

leftover_msec()
```

See the bottom of the [MP3::Tag](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyaz/MP3-Tag-0.92/Tag.pm) page for details